# Quote your references/links in English

Tags: discussion, sources-and-citations, languages

I recently came across an answer where a user [hyperlinked a page in Tamil Language](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/494/124). I thought to post this question so that it doesn't cause a problem in the long run because users with various sub Hindu castes will participate, so we need to normalize the language part.

If you are quoting any other language, make sure you explain the words written in there, also, when you hyperlink a source, make sure that the source page is in English and not any other language, for example, the answer I linked above is not referencing the article in English language, and its in Tamil instead.

As we know, India has thousands of different languages, so make sure to explain the terms of different language in English as well, for example, I like when the user [@jabahar](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/357/124)
quotes like..

> *ajanābhaṁ nāmaitad varṣaṁ bhāratam iti yata ārabhya vyapadiśanti.* [SB - 5.7.3]
>
> **Meaning**
> The name of this land was Ajanabha. It came to be known as Bharata after starting of his (King Bharata) reign.

---

So make sure that the text you quote here, if not in English language than explain the snippet in English and also when you link to the reference/source, make sure the article is written in English or the website is Multi Lingual ....